# Парсинг вложенных html таблиц с помощью регулярок

Tags: html, парсер

Есть вложенные таблицы, пример:

```
код код код <table>text text text text text <table>text222 text2222 text2222 text222 </table>text text </table> код код код
```

Вопрос. нужно составить регулярное выражение, чтобы в его границы попал "внутренняя" таблица.

Моих знаний хватило только на такое: <table[^<>]*?>.+?(?<=/table>)
Оно не подходит, тк захватывает оба открывающих тэга 
Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выбрать парный тег table, при условии, что внутри нет открывающего тега table. Можно использовать как ретроспективную, так и опережающую проверку (негативную). Последнее лучше поддерживается браузерами:

`<table[^<>]*?>(?:.(?!<table[^<>]*?>))*?<\/table>`

Comment: Благодарю, вы очень помогли!

Answer (score -1):

If you use a BeautifulSoup you can use: `sibling_soup.b.next_sibling` or `sibling_soup.c.previous_sibling` Documentation:https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).